# X-Forwarded-Host doesnt work in nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, kubernetes

**Update 2.** I want to add and forward all traffic to `localhost/admin/` instead of `localhost/`.

- App listen to those paths:

  - `localhost/` (then gets 302 to `localhost/login` by application),
  - `localhost/overview`,
  - `localhost/books/details`, etc.
- I want admin user to use those urls:

  - `localhost/admin/`(to get 302 `localhost/admin/login` by
    application)
  - `localhost/admin/overview`
  - `localhost/admin/books/details`
- With my reverse proxy (see below):

  - `localhost/admin/` (I get 302 `localhost/login` by application)

,

I could use also `ingrees-nginx-controller` instead of mounting file.

In docker nginx.conf (or similar to k8s)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
        ...
        location /admin {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host/admin;
        proxy_pass http://<conteiner2>.docker-network;
    }
    ... 
}
```

**Update1**
For kubernetes I am trying to setup the the `ingress-nginx`
For this I installed the `ingress-nginx-controller` and I setup the `ingress-nginx` using this YAML:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Host $host";
      more_set_headers "X-Real-IP $remote_addr";
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme";
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-Host $host/admin";
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /admin
          backend:
            serviceName: <app1>-admin
            servicePort: 8002
```

Comment: to use configuration snippet with the nginx-ingress controller use the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet on the ingress rules

Comment: Look update 1. How to use different annotation for diffrent location?

Comment: split the ingress rules on per path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there are a few things going on here; foremost:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host/admin;
proxy_pass http://<conteiner2>.docker-network;
```

is incorrect because `x-forwarded-HOST` should not contain a **uri**, as you have with `/admin`: it should just be the `$host`; what you really want is to update `proxy_pass` to contain the `$request_uri` as you can observe that the generated nginx.conf does when using the nginx Ingress controller. That wait the location's URI `/admin` along with whatever else matches in the location will be passed upstream as expected:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_pass http://<conteiner2>.docker-network$request_uri;
# or you're free to hard-code /admin if you prefer:
proxy_pass http://<conteiner2>.docker-network/admin;
```

Secondly, if you are experiencing that you want some `configuration-snippet:` applied to one URI but not both of them, then split out the two routes into two separate Ingress resources, so they can be managed independently:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      # this one just applies to /api
  name: test-ingress-api
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /api
          backend:
            serviceName: <app2>-api
            servicePort: 8000
---
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      # this one just applies for /admin
  name: test-ingress-admin
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /admin
          backend:
            serviceName: <app1>-admin
            servicePort: 8002
```

> Any ideas how to debug nginx proxy?

There are two great ways: first, grab the generated nginx.conf and read over it to see what you were expecting to happen versus what did happen:

```
kubectl cp ${the_nginx_controller_pod}:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ingress-nginx.conf
```

The other way is to turn the [nginx log level](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#error-log-level) to `debug` (which can be problematic if you're trying to debug in a production setting because of the absolutely insane amount of text it will generate, but it will almost certainly have the actual answer to whatever you are trying to debug):

```
# the ConfigMap may be named differently in your setup:
$ kubectl edit configmap nginx-ingress-controller

# and add:
data:
   error-log-level: debug

# then wait a few seconds for nginx to notice the configmap change
# and if it doesn't, kill the controller pods to force the reload
```

Comment: Look update 2. There is no `/admin` path inside the app.

Comment: Then it sounds like you'd want a [`rewrite-target:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) annotation on the 2nd Ingress (well, or continue with the `configuration-snippet:` and code that logic yourself)

Comment: It is not enough.. URL after localhost/admin gets 302 to loclahost/login. It should be 302 to localhost/admin/login. all traffic should go through localhost/admin/. Rewrite applies only to the first HTTP request and it is not forwarded.